# High DPI map in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I'm trying to display a map using Google Maps API. it works totally fine on desktop and iOS, but when I was trying it on Android (4.1) it is kind of blurry low DPI images.

One strange thing is that it does display maps with high DPI on the same device with CM 10 on it instead of the original firmware.

Is there a way to make sure it displays high DPI images with CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up your marker, MarkerOptions, set

optimized: false